# Scale Factors application not working on GEE PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, google-earth-engine, function, google-earth-engine-python-api, scale-factor

I'm trying to load some Lansadt 7 Collection 2 images on a QGIS project trought the following script:

```
import ee 
from ee_plugin import Map 

ecorregiones = ee.FeatureCollection('users/paullcfias/nacional/ecoreg_2021_buf1km')
zona = ecorregiones.filter('NOMBRE=="AMAZONIA"')

#*
 # Function to mask clouds based on the pixel_qa band of Landsat SR data.
 # @param {ee.Image} image Input Landsat SR image
 # @return {ee.Image} Cloudmasked Landsat image
 #
def cloudMaskL457(image):
  qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
  # If the cloud bit (5) is set and the cloud confidence (7) is high
  # or the cloud shadow bit is set (3), then it's a bad pixel.
  cloud = qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 5) \
                  .And(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 7)) \
                  .Or(qa.bitwiseAnd(1 << 3))
  # Remove edge pixels that don't occur in all bands
  mask2 = image.mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min())
  return image.updateMask(cloud.Not()).updateMask(mask2)


dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2') \
    .filter(ee.Filter.Or(
    ee.Filter.And(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 10),
                  ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 63)),
    ee.Filter.And(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 9),
                  ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 63)))) \
    .filterDate('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31') \
    .filter('CLOUD_COVER < 60') \
    .map(cloudMaskL457)

print(dataset)

# Applies scaling factors.
def applyScaleFactors(image):
  opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, {}, True) \
              .addBands(thermalBand, {}, True)

dataset = dataset.map(applyScaleFactors)

visualization = {
  'bands': ['SR_B3', 'SR_B2', 'SR_B1'],
  'min': 0.0,
  'max': 0.3,
}

listOfImages = dataset.toList(dataset.size())
size = dataset.size()
print(size)

#Loop to add all the images to the map
# client side loop
for i in range(0, 7, 1):
  image = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(i))
  Map.addLayer(image.clip(zona), visualization, str(i),0)


Map.centerObject(zona)
```

But I get an error that seems to be related to the applyScaleFactors function. I had ran the code section by section and the problem showed up at this point (line 49).

The js version of this code works well, and you can check it on this linK:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd55a2dd5270662d12ad271c03997850

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second element of `.addBands()` should be a list; which uses square brackets ( [] ), not braces/curly brackets ( {} ). Changing that makes your code run:

Edit: an empty list (`[]`) doesn't seem to work with a regex selection of bands. Either specify the names of the bands in a list (e.g., `['SR_B1', 'SR_B2', ...]`), or remove the argument. Fixed solution:

```
def applyScaleFactors(image):
  opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  thermalBand = image.select('ST_B6').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(srcImg = opticalBands, overwrite = True)\
              .addBands(srcImg = thermalBand, overwrite = True)
```

Comment: I was checking the output of my script and noted that the applyScaleFactors function is not being applied, i tried a lot different configurations but didn't managed to find out the solution.

Comment: Seems the empty list is the issue. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the script is working like it is supossed to do after trying your suggestion.